# partial match to compare 2 columns from different dataframes using fuzzy wuzzy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to compare this dataframe **df1**:

```
                         Product  Price
0               Waterproof Liner     40
1                   Phone Tripod     50
2               Waterproof Pants      0
3             baby Kids play Mat    985
4               Hiking BACKPACKS     34
5                security Camera    160
```

with df2 as shown below:

```
                                     Product      Id
0                    Home Security IP Camera  508760
1         Hiking Backpacks – Spring Products  287950
2                   Waterproof Eyebrow Liner  678897
3          Waterproof Pants – Winter Product  987340
4  Baby Kids Water Play Mat – Summer Product  111500
```

I want to compare **Product column** in **df1 with Product df2**. In order to find The **good id** of the product. And if there is **similarity < 80**  it will put **'Remove'** in the ID field
**NB:** The text of the **Product column in **df1 and df2** are not 100% matched**
Can Anyone help me with this or how can i use fuzzy wazzy to get the good id?

**Here is my code**

```
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import process

data1 = {'Product1': ['Waterproof Liner','Phone Tripod','Waterproof Pants','baby Kids play Mat','Hiking BACKPACKS','security Camera'],
'Price':[40,50,0,985,34,160]}

data2 = {'Product2': ['Home Security IP Camera','Hiking Backpacks – Spring Products','Waterproof Eyebrow Liner',
        'Waterproof Pants – Winter Product','Baby Kids Water Play Mat – Summer Product'],
        'Id': [508760,287950,678897,987340,111500],}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

dfm = pd.DataFrame(df1["Product1"].apply(lambda x: process.extractOne(x, df2["Product2"]))
                                   .tolist(), columns=['Product1',"match_comp", "Id"])
```

What i got :

```
                                    Product1  match_comp  Id
0                   Waterproof Eyebrow Liner          86   2
1                   Waterproof Eyebrow Liner          50   2
2          Waterproof Pants – Winter Product          90   3
3  Baby Kids Water Play Mat – Summer Product          86   4
4         Hiking Backpacks – Spring Products          90   1
5                    Home Security IP Camera          86   0
```

**What is expected to be :**

```
           Product  Price      ID
0    Waterproof Liner     40  678897
1        Phone Tripod     50  Remove
2    Waterproof Pants      0  987340
3  baby Kids play Mat    985  111500
4    Hiking BACKPACKS     34  287950
5     security Camera    160  508760
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a wrapper function:

```
def extract(s):
    name,score,_ = process.extractOne(s, df2["Product2"], score_cutoff=0)
    if score < 80:
        return 'Remove'
    return df2.set_index('Product2').loc[name, 'Id']
    

df1['ID'] = df1["Product1"].apply(extract)
```

output:

```
             Product1  Price      ID
0    Waterproof Liner     40  678897
1        Phone Tripod     50  Remove
2    Waterproof Pants      0  987340
3  baby Kids play Mat    985  111500
4    Hiking BACKPACKS     34  287950
5     security Camera    160  508760
```

*NB. the output is not exactly what you expect, you have to explain why rows 4/5 should be dropped*